# In MVVM How can i binding list in MODEL to combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In MODEL, there is a `list<string>`.

In VIEWMODEL, there is `IList<MODEL>`.

And I want to binding at ComboBox in VIEW

But when i binding `ItemsSource` to MODEL list, VIEW look to VIEWMODEL.

So binding alway fail. 
How can solve this problem?

```
class Model
{
        private IList<string> _comboItems;
        public IList<string> ComboItems
        {
            get => _comboItems;
            set => SetProperty(ref _comboItems, value);
        }
}

class ViewModel
{
        private IList<Model> _modelList;
        public IList<Model> ModelList
        {
            get => _modelList;
            set => SetProperty(ref _modelList, value);
        }
}
```

VIEW

```
<....>
   <GridView>
      <GridViewComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{binding ModelList}"/>
   </GridView>
```

Comment: Set the GridView datacontext to the ModelList and the column to the ComboItems

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have a datagrid and you want to populate a column by combobox with strings come from ComboItems. If  this is your goal: you have to keep in mind the following points.

1. you have to set the DataContext pointing your
2. Your ViewModel has, at least implements INotifyPropertyChanged, however if you have to do a large use of mvvm I suggest you to use one mvvm framework like [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) or [Caliburn Micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/) there are many however
3. the ItemsSource of your datagrid have to be able to notify changes to your view, it has to be something like an ObservableCollection or a BindingList
4. If you want to change the comboboxitems at runtime add or remove or items also ComboBoxItems has to be a BindingList ... it is not very good to  have bindinglist in a model.

well based on what I say you could do in this way I use traditional WPF your code seems to be UWP

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx /2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ModelList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyComboColumn" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource ="{Binding ComboItems}" BorderThickness="0" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;
        vm.ModelList = new BindingList<Model>();
        Model md = new Model();
        md.ComboItems = new List<string>();

        md.ComboItems.Add("string1");
        md.ComboItems.Add("string2");
        md.ComboItems.Add("string3");
        vm.ModelList.Add(md);

        md = new Model();
        md.ComboItems = new List<string>();

        md.ComboItems.Add("string4");
        md.ComboItems.Add("string5");
        md.ComboItems.Add("string6");
        vm.ModelList.Add(md);



    }
  }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private BindingList<Model> _modelList;
    public BindingList<Model> ModelList
    {
        get { return _modelList; }
        set { _modelList = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged("ModelList");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
public class Model
{
    private IList<string> _comboItems;
    public IList<string> ComboItems
    {
        get { return _comboItems; }
        set { _comboItems = value; }
    }
}
}
```